# solr lucene space search in word(String) break in 4 part than search with *

Tags: regex, string, solr, lucene, alfresco

I am new in lucene search
i have String in alfresco like citation **(1980) 01 CCH 2013 CochinTrib** and i have search string in 4 part that make complete citation string  citation =  **(year) volume Journal page_no**
than input give in search string year and volume search string is --> ***(1980) 01 *** that search result gives than also search when give year volume Journal page_no 
search string is --> ***(1980) 01 CCH 2013*** its also gives result but when give input string year journal page_no than search string is-***(1980) * CCH 2013*** than search result give 0

queries given below here

1. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"*(2013) *" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"*(2013) *")
2. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"* 37 *" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"* 37 *")
3. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"* CCH *" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"* CCH *")
4. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"* 320*" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"* 320*")
5. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"*(2013) 37 CCH 320*" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"*(2013) 37 CCH 320*")
6. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"*(2013) 37 CCH *" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"*(2013) 37 CCH *")
7. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"*(2013) 37 * 320*" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"*(2013) 37 * 320*")
8. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"*(2013) * CCH * 320*" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"*(2013) * CCH 320*")
9. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"* 37 CCH 320*" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"* 37 CCH 320*")
10. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"*(2013) 37 *" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"*(2013) 37 *")
11. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"*(2013) * CCH *" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"*(2013) * CCH *")
12. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"*(2013) * 320*" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"*(2013) * 320*")
13. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"* 37 CCH *" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"* 37 CCH *")
14. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"* 37 * 320*" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"* 37 * 320*")
15. +PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Case_Laws//cm:Cases//*" +(TYPE:"dTaxCaseLaws:caseLawsDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") +  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ ( @dTaxCaseLaws\:cchCitation:"* CCH 320*" OR @dTaxCaseLaws\:equivalentCitation:"* CCH 320*")

i have these queries when break sting in 4 part 
1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10,13,15 these query gives result but
7,8,11,12,14 query gives not gives result

but search string is same
how to search like this please help

Comment: A+ for effort... in English that is.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Could you please give a better description of the problem?

Comment: problem is string is (1980) 01 CCH 2013 CochinTrib search in lucene query  like that "*(1980) 01 * 2013*" and result give 0 but when search like that "*(1980) 01 *" it gives results. problem is string are break in 4 part than pass value in query so its difficult to  search example define above

Comment: problem also come when search white space like * * * create problem  i think

Comment: How do you split "(1980) 01 CCH 2013 CochinTrib" into "(year) volume Journal page_no"? Which are the tokens?

Comment: no in alfresco i have text citation and value is --(1980) 01 CCH 2013 CochinTrib and in UI i have 4 input box that for searching citation  its simply sting i am not split in alfresco i am only provide combination of search citation whan user enter only year than it give this year results

Comment: I really tried to understand your question. I don't get it. Sry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try also like this

> "\(1980)\ 2013"~5

its give you

Comment: its working thanks for given me solution